# Python Keras - Large MSE

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am new to KerasRegressor. I am trying to run neural net following this codes:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
seed = 1


def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model


estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100, verbose=False)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X_train,y_train, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))

estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction = estimator.predict(X_test)
```

Then I stumbled the following errors:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_45 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 10 but received input with shape [None, 39]
```

UPDATE: I fixed the error, it was in input_dim, which should be change to X_train.shape[-1]. However, I have a very large error, even after I try normalized X_train:

```
Results: -1674844.52 (3109620.06) MSE
```

I wonder how I should solve this? Thanks!

Comment: try input_dim=X_train.shape[-1]

Comment: It works but I don't know why I have large MSE: Results: -1824987.76 (3458596.67) MSE

Comment: Please give a proper title. It should be something like, "Python Keras - ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_45 is incompatible with the layer"

Comment: Make sure your X_train is normalized

Comment: Sure I will put proper title next time @AmayAgarwal

Comment: @ChandanMalla I have normalized my X_train but the MSE are still as large as before